# Remove Text within Header tags in the Excerpt

Tags: excerpt

With the default WordPress Excerpt function. WordPress strips the header tags (e.g. h1 tag) but keeps the unformatted text, that lies within the opening/closing of the h1 tag, displayed as part of the excerpt.

Is there a way, in addition of striping the h1 tag to also completely remove the text within the tag, when displaying the excerpt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing with regex, you might consider using a **user-defined excerpt** (i.e. a **manual excerpt**, which *retains* HTML tags, rather than relying solely on the automatic excerpt, which strips HTML tags.

Depending on your specific use case, using the manual excerpt for displaying HTML-formatted excerpts is usually an easier approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that works for me.

```
function bac_wp_strip_header_tags( $text ) {
     $raw_excerpt = $text;
     if ( '' == $text ) {
         //Retrieve the post content.
         $text = get_the_content(''); 
         //remove shortcode tags from the given content.
         $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
         $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
         $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

         //Regular expression that strips the header tags and their content.
         $regex = '#(<h([1-6])[^>]*>)\s?(.*)?\s?(<\/h\2>)#';
         $text = preg_replace($regex,'', $text);

         /***Change the excerpt word count.***/
         $excerpt_word_count = 55; //This is WP default.
         $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count);

         /*** Change the excerpt ending.***/
         $excerpt_end = '[...]'; //This is the WP default.
         $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);

         $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }
    add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'bac_wp_strip_header_tags', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse49280_strip_header_tags', 1 );
function wpse49280_strip_header_tags( $excerpt ) {
    // this is just an example, there is probably a better regex
    $regex = '#(<h([1-6])[^>]*>)\s?(.*)?\s?(<\/h\2>)#';
    return preg_replace(
        $regex,
        '',
        $excerpt
    );
}
```

It should be noted that regexing HTML is not the best solution, but I think it's the most practical for something simple such as this.

Comment: Thanks @m0r7if3r, your code is a step in the right direction. The regex variable need a ';' at the end (not a big deal). Also the $regex you defined does not seem to remove any text between headers. Noticed that your opening tag is h1-h6 but your closing tag is only h? Any ideas with the regex. Thanks.

Comment: @BoutrosAbiChedid Closing tag is self-referential. \2 means the value of the second parenthesis, which in this case is ([1-6]). What this does is prevent `<h1>foo <h3>bar</h3></h1>` from turning into `</h1>` instead of to `<h1>foo</h1>` then to an empty string. It should be removing any text in between as well, that's what the `.*` is for. You can test your regexes [here](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/).

Comment: thanks @m0r7if3r for the explanation. I tried the regex with the test tool and it works. But when I put your code above in the functions.php file of WordPress theme. It still shows the content between headers (but un-formatted). Please see this temporary example in my blog (first post) you see the default WordPress excerpt starting at: "header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6..." http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog?wptheme=Paper Wall    any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try using `get_the_excerpt` instead of `the_excerpt` as your hook.

Comment: I already did that, did not make any difference. Other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried testing it to make sure it's actually the regex that's failing, and not some other portion of the code?

Comment: The Regex works fine under normal conditions, but the problem is the WP filter hook, it is hooking too late even with high priority of 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3148/discussion-between-m0r7if3r-and-boutros-abichedid)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @m0r7if3r for all your help. I don't think I would have figured out the Regex part.
This is the code I am using and it works:

```
function wp_strip_header_tags( $text ) {

$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    //Retrieve the post content.
    $text = get_the_content(''); 
    //remove shortcode tags from the given content.
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
}
    $regex = '#(]*>)\s?(.*)?\s?()#';
    $text = preg_replace($regex,'', $text);

    /***Change the excerpt word count.***/
    $excerpt_word_count = 60; //WP default is 55
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count);

    /*** Change the excerpt ending.***/
    $excerpt_end = '[...]'; //This is the WP default.
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);

    $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );

    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_strip_header_tags', 5);
```